# Can I ask this on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask which GUI tool kit is best to use with Clojure for creating very simple UIs.

Is that question okay for Stack Overflow? Or another Stack Exchange site?

Edit:

Here is what I would post:

The long and short of this question is which GUI tool kits work with Clojure? Here are the details.

I want to create very simple (simple GUI) applications that will run on Windows, without investing in a huge GUI design effort.

I would like to write these applications in Clojure, and also take advantage of simple GUI packages.

Which is the simplest tool that can be used with Clojure to create a primitive UI? By primitive UI I mean something like an old Windows 3.1 (16-bit) modal dialog box.

Comment: You **can** ask just about anything.  What you should be asking here is **should** I ask this on SE, or will it be downvoted and closed with a venegance (it'll be DVd and closed, FYI)

Comment: The problem is asking a [*good subjective question*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) while avoiding the appearance you are shopping for a new color to paint your bikeshed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say no point blank, but some of these do get accepted on SO.  For yours to be accepted you're going to need to provide more criteria.  As-is, you'll get answers like "Use X, it rules!"

By providing criteria, you'll get better answers — better suited to your use case, and providing an explanation of the recommendation.  Such answers are much easier to evaluate and help avoid the "too subjective" problem.

See also: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Yeah - like, "I need a GUI tool kit for Clojure that does x, y, and z - what's the best option"

Comment: To elaborate on Matthew's suggestion of providing more criteria: You're getting a start with "creating very simple UI's", but if you're going to ask a question like that, you should be VERY specific about what your requirements are.  Any question like this is always going to be dangerously close to being purely subjective.

Comment: I've edited the original question, and added to it what I was originally going to write in SO.